# Close all Bootstrap tabs at start

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

How can I close all Bootstrap tabs at once?
I need to have all tabs closed at start, then use it as usual, but if some tab is open and I click again it will close - same as Bootstrap accordion functionality.

Code is same as on Bootstrap page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane in active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Fisrt tab is always open. When I remove active class it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: Code is same as on Bootstrap page:

Comment: You remove the active on both the tab-pane and the nav-tabs and it closes all the panes and works fine

Comment: What do you mean "close" the tabs? Only one is visible at a time, but they are not opened or closed, per se.

Comment: I cannot find any good solution, so I created custom responsive tabs-collapse plugin for this purpose. But very thanks for helps.